# Erro: The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer um **POST** em  uma WebApi que está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.
>
> ExceptionMessage: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Arquivo' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.
>
> ExceptionType: System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException   em System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      em System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Estou tentando realizar um upload de um arquivo de texto (.txt)

Segue o código do meu controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUpload()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Texto");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    try
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
       // This illustrates how to get the file names.

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

e da minha *view* de upload

```
<form action="http://localhost:61877/api/Arquivos" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label for="relatedFile">File:</label>
    <input name="relatedFile" size="40" type="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para receber arquivo via WebAPI, e leitura dos dados é um pouco diferente de apenas emviar POST no formato JSON.

Quando se realiza um POST com tipo `multipart`, deve-se realizar a leitura com um `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`.

Segue exemplo de como fazer essa leitura:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile() 
{ 
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request; 
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) 
    { 
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType); 
    } 

    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"); 
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root); 

    var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider). 
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o => 
    { 

        string file1 = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;
        // this is the file name on the server where the file was saved 

        return new HttpResponseMessage() 
        { 
            Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.") 
        }; 
    } 
    ); 
    return task; 
}
```

Voce pode ler mais sobre isso nesse artigo sobre [enviando arquivos em formato Multipart MIME](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2).

Comment: Editei minha pergunta. Porém ainda não consegui realizar o Post. Agora está me retornando a seguinte mensagem: *Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Path foi detectado no cliente (>).*